# How can I apply the same logic to multiple tables that have the same number of columns and data types?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple tables with identical number of fields (and data types).

Here are two examples (DDL to create these tables at the bottom):

Animal

```
AnimalGroup Name                 
----------- ---------------------
G111        Dog,Cat,Rabbit       
G210        Squirrel,Fox,Chipmunk
```

Car

```
CarGroup Name                       
-------- --------------------------
G100      Mustang,Explorer,Silverado 
G300      Equinox,Expedition,X3
```

Most of the time people would query the tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Animal
WHERE  Name LIKE '%,Cat,%'
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Car
WHERE Name LIKE '%,Equinox,%'
```

I want to query these tables so that I get a result set in a better, more normalized form. In this explanation, I'll say that I just want to split the delimited values into rows by the comma delimiter, but in reality, I do much more manipulation.

So I've written a view that transforms them to something like this:

Animal_View

```
AnimalGroup Name                 
----------- ---------------------
G111        Dog
G111        Cat
G111        Rabbit
G210        Squirrel
G210        Fox
G210        Chipmunk
```

So now, someone can write their query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Animal
WHERE  Name = 'Cat'
```

I know, really ground breaking stuff here...

Here's my dilemma. There's a lot that happens in this view....and it's the exact same manipulation that would happen for the Car table...but because it's a view, I would need to create another one, reference the Car table, repeat all of this code, etc. The only two differences between any of these dozens of views are the table name and the first column name. I can get around the first column name issue with a CTE with predefined column names and a "SELECT *" against the table name. But still, a new view for every single table with 99.9% of the same code--only a different table name.

```
CREATE VIEW Animal_View
AS

WITH CTE1(Grp, Name)
AS (SELECT *
    FROM   Animal)
...a bunch of manipulation
.
.
.
SELECT Grp, Name 
FROM CTE3
```

```
CREATE VIEW Car_View
AS

WITH CTE1(Grp, Name)
AS (SELECT *
    FROM   Car)
...a bunch of manipulation
.
.
.
SELECT Grp, Name 
FROM CTE3
```

So because the tables have the same structure and data types, I was wondering how I might be able to do this without creating a bunch of views. I was thinking maybe a table-valued function could work here.

What I want to ultimately be able to do is say to people who write select queries against the base tables: "if you want this animal or car data formatted nicely and in a way you can easily filter values, take your normal query of":

```
SELECT *
FROM   Animal
```

"and add this line:"

```
CROSS APPLY dbo.SampleTVF(AnimalGroup, Name) ca
```

"and change your '*' to a 'ca.*'"

so it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Animal
CROSS APPLY dbo.SampleTVF(AnimalGroup, Name) ca
```

And they would get a nicely-formatted view of their data  and be able to filter on individual fields and terms without having to use LIKE. Also, I wouldn't need to create a bunch of almost identical views.

But obviously, even though all of these tables are the same structure and data types, that first field name in the TVF arguments would need to change depending on the table you're querying, so unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to universally just say, "paste this line".

....Also, even if they did paste the CROSS APPLY line and update that first field, filtering on the fields that come back from the TVF is soooo slow compared to the view. In an individual view against that table with all the manipulation, the results come back in 1-2 seconds. When I use essentially the same logic but in a TVF and filter on one of its returned fields, results never come back.

Can I accomplish this, or am I fighting a losing battle? Since users are writing SELECT queries, TVFs and Views were what came to mind as potential options (as opposed to stored procedures), but maybe there's some other way I could approach this to format the data and make it easy for users to query...

Thank you in advance!

A couple of other notes: This is SQL Server 2016. I can't create indexes.

Here's the DDL to create and populate the Animal and Car tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Animal(
    AnimalGroup varchar(5) NULL,
    [Name] varchar(200) NULL,
    Color varchar(200) NULL
)

INSERT dbo.Animal (AnimalGroup, [Name], Color) VALUES (N'G1', N'Dog,Cat,Rabbit', N'Brown,Tan,White')
GO
INSERT dbo.Animal (AnimalGroup, [Name], Color) VALUES (N'G2', N'Squirrel,Fox,Chipmunk', N'Brown,Orange,Brown')
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Car(
    CarGroup varchar(5) NULL,
    [Name] varchar(200) NULL,
    Color varchar(200) NULL
)

INSERT dbo.Car (CarGroup, [Name], Color) VALUES (N'G1', N'Mustang,Explorer,Silverado', N'Blue,Black,Green')
GO
INSERT dbo.Car (CarGroup, [Name], Color) VALUES (N'G2', N'Equinox,Expedition,X3', N'Green,Red,Gray')
GO

SELECT *
FROM   Animal

SELECT *
FROM   Car
```

Comment: I guess the *real* answer is to sort out your DB and normalize all those tables into rows

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`STRING_SPLIT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is available in SQL Server 2016 and onward now. You should be able to use that generically for each of your tables (or any table honestly, that has a string-based field). It works similarly to how you were thinking in regards to leveraging a **Table Valued Function**.

And if you care about performance, or legacy support, this [SQL Performance article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) provides a ton of *old-school* ways to accomplish this.

Speaking of which, I believe this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926996/5059085) is one of the more common legacy implementations. Here's the code for reference:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string_to_column] (
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @out_put TABLE (
    [column_id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @pos INT = 0,
        @len INT = 0

    SET @string = CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@string, 1) != @delimiter
                THEN @string + @delimiter
            ELSE @string
            END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @len = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + 1) - @pos
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, @len)

        INSERT INTO @out_put ([value])
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)) AS [column]

        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @pos + @len) + 1
    END

    RETURN
END
```

As discussed in the comments, you can either overhaul the native `STRING_SPLIT()` function, or extend any of the legacy methodologies mentioned above, and create your own **Table Valued Function** that does the splitting and additional logic you need to accomplish. That way the code is refactored all into one place and you can just join to that **Table Valued Function** in your Views so that your repeated code is minimal like so:

```
-- Normalized Animal View DDL
SELECT AnimalGroup, SplitValue AS Name
FROM Animal
CROSS APPLY dbo.CustomStringSplitFunction(',', Name)

-- Normalized Car View DDL
SELECT CarGroup, SplitValue AS Name
FROM Car
CROSS APPLY dbo.CustomStringSplitFunction(',', Name)
```

Or you can just provide the line of code `CROSS APPLY dbo.CustomStringSplitFunction(',', Name)` to your users since it's generic, if you really don't want to create Views.

Comment: JD, Thank you. Yes, I'm familiar with STRING_SPLIT (and its many limitations), but my question isn't about how to split strings, it's about how to encapsulate the same set of logic and manipulation such that I can apply it to many different tables and not have to create all of these objects in the database. Plus, splitting is just one of many things that happens to this data.

Comment: @MikeS I added a link to legacy methodologies too which you can modify as needed. Regardless I think you'll need to make Views to encapsulate what you want to accomplish, but yes the main logic can be refactored and live in a **Table Valued Function** that you can just join to your Tables within your Views, to keep the Views to barebones code.

Comment: @MikeS I also added one legacy implementation of a Split function which you can customize with your manipulations and then I added examples of what your Views would look like when calling the custom **Table Valued Function** (in case I wasn't clear enough in my last comment).

Comment: @MikeS Also after reading your question a little closer, I see you're under the impression you would need to pass in `AnimalGroup` column into your **Table Valued Function** but that is not true. You only need to pass in the name of the column that needs to be split, in this case the `Name` column that is common among all of your Tables, and the delimiter you need to split on, which is a comma, such as in my very last **DDL** code examples in my answer. (I originally included the table names in the example but that's not required so I just removed them). This way, if you are adamant on not...

Comment: ...creating Views for your Tables, you can still provide your users a generic line of code they can remember to use when they want to normalize the data like so: `CROSS APPLY CustomStringSplitFunction(',', Name)`.